# Using valgrind on a Mac

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, valgrind, gmp

I have a piece of c++ code about 600 lines long which currently doesn't run due to seg fault. I have run gdb but it isn't really helping me as I don't know what I am looking for. I have also run valgrind which I have been led to believe is more helpful, but I am working on a mac and valgrind doesn't really work on mac (says so in the warning when I use it, I am running OSX 10.8). I don't have a linux box and so can't run valgrind properly. Is there anyone willing to run my code through valgrind to find the issue, or are there websites that do this?? The reason I ask here is because I have found websites, but because I am using the gmp bignum library, the website just kicks back errors about the library not being there because they don't have it.

Edit: The code is at http://www.filedropper.com/tammesa7 I shan't post it here as it is long and messy!

Comment: Have you tried inserting breakpoints to narrow down where the error is occurring?

Comment: One option is to install a free virtual machine like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).  You can cleanly install any other OS on that and use the tools available.

Comment: @Boumbles Yes, I have an issue with the mpf_urandomb() function, however by running the loop containing this on its own it runs fine, so I was pretty sure I understood how it worked. When putting it into this program though I get seg faults...

Comment: Another option is to make a similar - but not long and messy - program that exhibits the same problem you're having and post *that* here.  Good luck!

Comment: The reason you have bugs is because it is long and messy. Break it down into small parts and test them separately.

Comment: I agree with Peter Wood on this. Your method is extremely long and you've got way too many single letter variable names. Give your variables meaningful names, split up the functionality of your code into many different methods with meaningful names. Once your code is easier to read it will be a lot easier to figure out where and why your error is happening.

Comment: Error was due to lack of initialising the random generator. Also Thanks for the debugging tips. I think it is obvious I need to learn more about functions and make the code prettier, but the variable names are meaningful to me, although that obviously doesn't help the general reader.

Comment: @DrewDormann If you put up your virtual box comment as an answer I shall accept it, as I didn't realise that was available to me.

Comment: Why don't you run it in Xcode? It's going to do exactly what you want for debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to install a free virtual machine like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

You can cleanly install any other OS on that and use the tools available.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to debug code.

1. Running in a debugger and using the "backtrace" or "view stack" type options will tell you where it crashed. Assuming it does crash.
2. Adding logging. Sprinkle the code with `printf("I'm in functon %s\n", __FUNCTION__);` or something similar. Printing variable values and comparing with what you "expect".
3. Adding code to catch "bad behaviour". For example, check for NULL pointers, indexes out of range, and so on.
4. Reduce the relevant code. Remove functions - for example, make the whole function a comment, or add a "return" at the top of the function. If the problem goes away, undo your last change, and try to reduce it a little bit to see what happens then.
5. Reduce the input parameters. If your code is using a large data-file as input, try it with a smaller one. Try removing certain data - if the problem goes away, then you know it's (probably) in the rest of the data.